# Sequencing ActionBar Items

Tags: android

Currently the Items in Action Bar seem to be sequenced by default as:

1. Order in which menu XML files are inflated. For example calls to `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or `onCreateActionMode()` in a `Activity` class hierarchy.
2. The individual order in which action items are declared in menu XML files.

Now problem is with point 1 stated above. Is there another way to ensure a proper sequence ? That is, action bar items are arranged in a particular sequence like more usable ones first, and less usable ones can rest in overflow menu.

As far I know, there is only `showAsAction` property for menu items and is not enough for sequencing items. Is there another property that can be used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current API there's no way to do this. Hijacking `super()` calls in another (tough and ugly) option.